# How do I successfully create gitlab tags

Tags: gitlab

When I trying to create tags for my project on gitlab
it shows,

> notice: successful!

But I can't find tags. My account is the owner of my project.
I don't know why this is happening.
My gitlab is running,looks like well done.

Answer (score 0):

You can find them under https://gitlab_instance/namespace/project/tags or Repository > Tags.